# global в функции это нормально?

Tags: php, global-variables

есть класс, который осуществляет работу с БД
есть функция, которая возвращает определенную строку, в т.ч. с помощью класса

использовать класс внутри функции получилось только с помощью global
пример кода

```
<?php

$db = new TestClass();

function getContent($param1, $param2){
   global $db;
   return $db->blabla('SELECT ... ', $param1, $param2);
}
```

это нормально? или лучше использовать что-то другое для определения $db внутри функции?

Comment: Определить параметром: `function getContent($param1, $param2, $db){` или `function getContent($param1, $param2, TestClass $db){` ... А вообще лучше методы делать ... Можно наследоваться от `TestClass` ... Можно ещё по-разному ... Но так, как вы сделали — не айс — спрятать и никому не показывать. А лучше уничтожить :D

Comment: использование **global** ужасно... лучше всего использовать классы.

Comment: Для небольших скриптов вполне нормально, польза от отказа от global ощущается с увеличением сложности программной системы.

Comment: думаю вам поможет singleton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Идеальным ответом является комментарий от Vladimir Gamalian:

> Для небольших скриптов вполне нормально, польза от отказа от global ощущается с увеличением сложности программной системы.

От себя я бы определил так:

Если, как в данном случае, код пишется процедурно, то ничего плохого в таком использовании global нет.

Вообще, global ругают по двум причинам. Первая - это действительно страх и ужас, когда этот оператор используется не по назначению, для передачи *локальных* переменных в функцию, что катастрофически запутывает программу. Допустим, у нас есть функция

```
function f1() {
    global $var
    $var++;
}
```

и где-то в коде программы встречается вот такой кусок:

```
$var = 1;
f1();
```

Что произошло с переменной $var, что делала функция f1() - из этого кода решительно не понятно. 
Такого кода надо избегать всегда. Вместо global в данном случае надо всегда писать так:

```
function f1($var) {
    return $var++;
}
```

и использовать

```
$var = 1;
$var = f1($var);
```

Вторая причина - это, условно говоря, невозможность подменить $db на лету.
В более сложных программных системах иногда возникает необходимость подменять тот или иной сервис в зависимости от задачи. К примеру, вместо mysql использовать, скажем, MongoDB. Для одной и той же задачи, но в зависимости от контекста. И в этом случае global станет помехой, и нам нужно будет изобретать более сложные способы передачи сервисов в функцию.

Но до тех пор пока наша программа достаточно простая, не использует ООП, и при этом мы используем этот оператор для действительно **глобальных** сервисов, использование global вполне оправдано.